# Does the atom get the impulse from a photon?

Tags: energy, photons, atoms

A photon has both impulse and energy. If it is absorbed in an atom from level E1 to E2 what happen to the impulse.
Does the atom acquire the impulse of the photon? If so it would get some acceleration and this is some excessive kinetic Ek?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one account for the momentum of an absorbed photon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/212614/)

Comment: Hi @JohnRennie, This answer is huge! I never realized it is so complicated. I need a week to follow it. Can you get a short answer? Does p go to the electron or to the nucleus?