How is potential energy incorporated into mass in special relativity?
I've seen it said before that we often ignore potential energy in relativity because it can be included in the mass term. It is commonly said that a hydrogen atom has less mass than the sum of its parts, due to the negative binding potential energy, for example. But I haven't seen an intuitive argument for why this would be the case. In fact, it seems counterintuitive.
Suppose you have two equal masses, separated by a distance $d$. If they are both stationary, and noninteracting, then their total mass is $2m$. If you were to apply some force $F$ for an instant $dt$ to the first mass, and the same force to the second mass, the system's center of mass would gain a velocity $dv=Fdt/m$. While center of mass is not talked about often in relativity, I understand that it does have a definition, though obscure.
Now suppose one of these masses has a positive charge, and the other a negative charge, of equal magnitudes. There is now a potential energy of interaction which differs from the potential energy the masses would have if they were infinitely far apart. While it is true that they will attract each other, their changes in motion oppose each other. Applying the same force to both charges, the center of mass seems that it should still gain the same $dv$; in fact, the deviations in the two individual masses from this velocity due to their mutual attraction should exactly cancel. It seems that mass 1 should have a velocity $dv+dv_{0}$, while mass 2 should have a velocity $dv-dv_{0}$, where $dv_{0}$ is the change due to their attraction.
So if the center of mass gains the same change in velocity for the same force in both situations, how does the system with the electrostatic potential have less mass? Is mass not related to how hard something is to accelerate? Where is my misunderstanding?

Does this answer your question? Why does binding energy of particles, which constitutes most of macroscopic mass, make them harder to accelerate?

For even more details, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/804393/364064

I'm not sure. I guess I'm more looking to understand why potential energy can be treated the same as, say, thermal energy. Kinetic/thermal energy seem very different in character from potential energy, even though they are both forms of energy, and while I can visualize why maybe increasing thermal energy would make acceleration harder, I can't do the same with potential energy.

I'm trying to understand this more by visualizing what's happening to the individual particles experiencing the potential that makes the system harder to push around. I don't know if this is possible.

That is why I gave the first comment before the 2nd. You have to stop thinking of inertia as a property of mass. It is a property of energy. When an object has more energy, it will have more inertia, i.e. by definition, harder to push around. When negative potential energy robs that energy, then it becomes easier to push around. There is no visualisation possible. This is purely a mathematical connection, consequence, and not visualisable.

I was under the impression that it might be. I thought back to the expression for momentum in relativity. If you imagine a box with particles bouncing around inside, their momenta are higher for a higher box temperature. Since momentum is nonlinear with velocity, the individual particles are harder to accelerate when they move faster, which seems to explain why a thermal object is more massive. But maybe I misunderstand.

Back in old Newtonian mechanics, you operationally defined mass (by ratio of weights) and then used mass and velocity to define momentum and energy. In modern physics, momentum and energy are upgraded into fundamental entities on their own right, and for fundamental particles that are free, their invariant rest mass energies identify which particle they are. Otherwise, in a system of particles, the potential energies and other such things modify the rest mass energies. A thermal object is just more energetic, and thus has more inertia. Momenta and energy determine velocity and rest mass.

More on potential energy in SR.
